# Error converting data type varchar to float when parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which will parse a raw data. The code below is the part of the  stored procedure. I'm testing it and it returns an error 'Error converting data type varchar to float.'. If you will notice I change the raw data in KM2 both in case and in else.

Can someone help me how to make it right, Thanks in advance for all the help guys.

```
SELECT [Account]  = LEFT('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3',CHARINDEX(',','351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3') - 1),
   [TrxDateTime] = cast(stuff(stuff(stuff((SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 27, 12)), 7,0,' '), 10,0,':'), 13,0,':') as datetime),
   [PhilTime] = GETDATE(),
   [GPSStatus] = CASE WHEN(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 40, 1) = 'A')
                THEN 'OK'
                ELSE 'Message Not Valid' END,
   [Lat] = cast(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 42, 9) as float)/100,
   [Long] = cast(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 53, 10) as float)/100,
   [Speed2] = cast(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 65, 1) as float)*1.852/1000,
   [ENGINE] = CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1G,141007034741,A,1430.4280N,12100.0551E,0.0,330,0.8,20000000;2G,141007034741,11,22.8,12.87,04.09,273342044.3', 77, 1) = '2')
                THEN 'ON'
                 ELSE 'OFF' END,
   [KM2] = CASE WHEN(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11) like '%,%')
                THEN 'NULL'
                --ELSE 'BDADADADAD' END,
                ELSE round(cast(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1) END,
   [PlateNo] = NULL,
   [ProcStatus] = '0';
```

Error I kept on running into is

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Comment: Change `THEN 'NULL'` to `THEN NULL`...

Comment: Also, I really hope you don't ever store data like this in a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your definition of [KM2]. Change it by unquoting 'NULL' to NULL as per the following:

```
...
[KM2] = CASE WHEN(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11) like '%,%')
            THEN NULL
            ELSE round(cast(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1) END,
...
```

Comment: Your data looks like it is coming from a CSV file. It would be much better (faster) to import this raw data into a table using BULK INSERT (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188365.aspx). Your stored proc then becomes much simpler (and quicker). You would then query the new table with a SP. As it stands your SP is a very inefficient parser.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a dual problem here.
Lets take a section of your code

```
--ELSE 'BDADADADAD' END,
ELSE
round(cast(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1) END,
```

You need to change one of two things. Either `'NULL'` in the `IF` to `NULL` or numeric value, OR
Statement in your `ELSE` should return `Varchar`. But if your `ELSE` will hit in its current form, it will still be an issue because of what I explained below. For example, this works:

```
select  CASE WHEN(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11) like '%,%')
            THEN 'Null'
            ELSE cast(round(cast(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)as float)
            /3600, 0, 1)as varchar) END
```

It works because `if` and `else` return same data type and `else` is never hit. And check this out - this works too:

```
 select  CASE WHEN(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11) like '%,%')
            THEN 1
            ELSE cast(cast(right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)as float)
            /3600, 0, 1) END
```

Now. look at this part: `right('351856040520389,241111;1G,141209203228,A,1437.3980N,12103.6893E,0.0,44,0.8,01004000', 11)`
It will return `.8,01004000`

Now, you enclose this result into `cast` - `cast('.8,01004000' as float)`

There your problem - ".8,01004000" doesn't look as string representation of float.

Now, check this out

`select CAST('.8,01004000' as float)` - NOT Working (Error converting data type varchar to float)
`select CAST('.801004000' as float)` - Working

Comment: No, for this specific data that ELSE isn't reached because it is filtered out in the NOT LIKE '%,%' at the beginning of that CASE expression. The string that is attempting to be converted to float is 'NULL'.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It depends on how you look at the problem. If the `ELSE` part would be returning 'varchar' so the `'NULL'` in the `IF` part would be working. It is unclear here which part is wrong. So, I picked second one